# Xamarin Forms PanGesture within a View

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, gesture

I'm having a problem with the PanGestuer behaviour in Xamarin Form. This is my page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Xamarin_Test"
         x:Class="Xamarin_Test.MainPage">
  <StackLayout x:Name="parentFrame" Margin="100" BackgroundColor="Gray">
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="parentLayout" BackgroundColor="Red">
        <local:PanContainer x:Name="parentContainer" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
            <Image x:Name="panImage" Source="MonoMonkey.jpg"
                       WidthRequest="{Binding Path=Width, Source={x:Reference Name=parentFrame}}"
                       HeightRequest="{Binding Path=Height, Source={x:Reference Name=parentFrame}}"/>
        </local:PanContainer>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**PanContainer.cs**

```
public class PanContainer : ContentView
{
    double x, y;

    public PanContainer()
    {
        var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        panGesture.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);
    }

    void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.StatusType)
        {         
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                // Translate and ensure we don't pan beyond the wrapped user interface element bounds.
                Content.TranslationX = Math.Max(Math.Min(0, x + e.TotalX), -Math.Abs(Content.Width - App.ScreenWidth));
                Content.TranslationY = Math.Max(Math.Min(0, y + e.TotalY), -Math.Abs(Content.Height - App.ScreenHeight));
                break;

            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                // Store the translation applied during the pan
                x = Content.TranslationX;
                y = Content.TranslationY;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The image loads with correct size (within the StackLayout borders, for better testing I colorized the elements). The panning works to the left and to the upper way of the image, but overlays the white area. How can I handle panning, so that the moved image is only visible within my `panContainer`?

Comment: I think you just have to set the cliptobounds property of your pancontiner to 'true' which should keep child views inside it's constaints.

Comment: That's it! Sometimes it can be so easy ^^ Thank you!